# Can't choose right webcam in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, webcam, getusermedia

I can't choose right webcam in Google Chrome.
Chrome detects my webcams correctly, but I am unable to chose one of them from list because it is in a disabled state where Chrome is always choosing Facetime HD Camera instead of the default webcam that was selected in Options.

Screenshot: https://tppr.me/WC94p

Website where I have tested: https://chatruletka.com / https://ruletka.chat

Comment: can I be marked as the answer please :)

Comment: @Marcus your answer is not working for me. Changing the setting to a different camera has no effect for me, it continues to use my built-in webcam (for https://app.chime.aws).

Comment: Having the same issue, and Marcus' answer doesn't work for me either. I've had to physically unplug the wrong camera so that Chrome would be forced to pick the right one next time.

Comment: Hi, I come across the same issue, I resolved it, I hope this could help. In my situation, I have two cameras, front and rear, if front is used by another program or webpage, chrome will automatically use rear, and it's not changable so if you want to use front in chrome, just close other progam or webpage.

Answer (score 31):

> chrome://settings/content/camera

The quick select is currently disabled in Chrome. You need to type the above into the URL bar in chrome to pick which webcam you want to use. I have had chrome "bug" a few times where I have had to kill chrome in task manager and restart the app to successfully swap the camera. You might need to do the above and refresh a few times.

Also if you ask for a resolution which isn't supported by your main camera it will attempt to get it from another source. I have encountered this a few times on Android when asking for a 720x1280 feed. Instead of the front camera being used the browser decided to use the back camera.

To truly solve this problem you should allow the user to select which webcam they want to use. Below is the official cross-platform example from the webrtc GitHub repo which achieves this. It also forces a specific camera to be used via the deviceId

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

Comment: This answer does not work for me. Changing the camera in settings has no effect. Works fine with Firefox, but I can't use Firefox for whiteboard sharing in my main use case: https://app.chime.aws

Comment: This will be due to how Chime has been engineered. Typically a product should also allow you to pick which device you want to use. When I have encountered this issue I have used ManyCam to try force Chime/chome to use what I needed. May work for Chime?

Comment: The link to github is a good demonstration of in-browser camera selection for troubleshooting, however the link to chrome camera settings does not appear to allow ANY setting on a per-camera basis, including default camera.  (On Windows 10)

Comment: This doesn't work for me either and it also doesn't work on Firefox. The website in question is https://account.edx.org/id-verification/take-portrait-photo. My webcam works fine on all other sites and applications.

Comment: Try to select right webcam here https://ruletka.chat

Comment: @user3925803 if other websites work, and this one doesn't, this typically means they did not code their solution to work in a cross-browser manner. The link I sent can only change the camera for that website, not another website, it should be cross-browser. I advise you sending Edx a bug report and use a browser and device they recommend.

Comment: @Marcus, is it anyhow possible to set default camera in chrome on android?

Comment: Thank you - this was such a pain at the tutorial I had to give this morning and using the link I was able to select the correct camera right away.